# How to add value to compare it in xtype

Tags: extjs

Some help please.
I'm trying to display a xtype depending on value that i get from database.
I have created the store to fetch data from my server side, and it receives only boolean value true or false nothing else.

```
var hidden= Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
                    {
                        fields: ['hidden'],
                        autoLoad: true,
                        proxy:
                        {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url: 'hidden/compare',
                            reader:
                            {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'data'
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Here is the example what i want, but i don't know what to add instead value_from_the_store

```
text: 'Now you see me, now you don't',
xtype: value_from_the_store == false ?  'hidden' : 'textfield',
```

Comment: Which version of ext are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for `Ext.data.Store`, you'll see several functions that allow you to access the data in the store.

[Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)

I'm not sure which record you want to access, or if there is only one record, but you can get records by index using `getAt`, or by ID using `getById`. You can get the first record using `first`. There are also several `find` functions, which allow you to search for a specific record.

Since you said there is only one record, you could just use `first`. You'll also need to get the specific field in the record using `get('hidden')`.

```
xtype: hidden.first().get('hidden') ? 'hidden' : 'textfield',
```

Comment: There is only one record and that is false.

Comment: Did you verify that your store actually has any data?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can try this fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lho

I've created this fiddle in Ext 5 but you can still make it work in 4. Hope this helps.

Here is the same fiddle for Ext 4.2 - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lji

And in the fiddle, instead of calling the function, you can even do this -

```
xtype: store.getAt([0]).get('hidden')? 'hidden' : 'textfield'
```

Another way of fetching the value from the store is by -

```
store.findRecord('hidden', 'true').get('hidden')
```

**store.findRecord('fieldName', 'Either a string that the field value should begin with, or a RegExp to test against the field.')**

Here's your [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findRecord) to the API doc

Comment: You'll just have to modify how you get that data from the store.

Comment: When i try it this is what i get:

store.getData is not a function

Comment: Yes, that's because getData is not present in Ext 4. I've mentioned that I did it in 5.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new fiddle for ext 4.2

Comment: For some unknown reason to me it returns this: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined  in this line getType(store.getAt([0]).get('hidden') )

Comment: Try this way then - store.findRecord('hidden', 'true').get('hidden')